# JSF - Unhide jsf component when clicking another component

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf, myfaces

I'm trying to have a button that brings up an upload dialog. 
The way i'm trying to achieve this is similar to this:

```
<h:outputText value="Click Me" id="testit">
  <a4j:support reRender="hideme" event="onclick" action="#{actions.switchTestRendered}"/>
</h:outputText>
<h:outputText id="hideme" value="back" rendered="#{actions.testRendered}"/>
```

With code in the backing bean:

```
private boolean testRendered = false;
public String switchTestRendered(){
 setTestRendered(!isTestRendered());
 System.out.println("Current Status:"+isTestRendered());
 return "success";
}

public void setTestRendered(boolean testRendered) {
  this.testRendered = testRendered;
}

public boolean isTestRendered() {
  return testRendered;
}
```

When I press the 'click me' label I can see that the switchTestRendered is run but the 'hideme' component does not reveal.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.
I should have reRendered the parent of the element which I'm trying to hide/show.
In other words:

```
<a4j:support reRender="hideme" event="onclick" action="#{actions.switchTestRendered}"/>
```

should be:

```
<a4j:support reRender="father_of_hideme" event="onclick" action="#{actions.switchTestRendered}"/>
```

Thanks!
Ben.

Answer (score 0):

From the code it can only be seen that after 'Click me' the 'hide' component renderer is not updating. You have to find out why